# laravel multiple fields upload

Tags: php, laravel

i want to loop through the multiple input fields on html blade so as to be able to upload them to my database using the laravel query builder. But the problem here is that its telling me:"Attempt to read property "drugid" on string"

lets assume this is one of the html inputs:

```
<input type="text" name="drugname[]">
<input type="text" name="drugname[]">
<input type="text" name="drugname[]">
```

Next was on my controller where i looped the fields in order for it to upload to the database

```
 public function prescribedrugs(Request $presdrug){
    $validator = Validator::make($presdrug->all(), [
        'consultclinic' => 'required|string',
        'drugdiagnosis' => 'required|string',
        'drugpassword' => 'required|string',
    ]);
    $getuser = new Getloggedinuserservice();
    $getloggedinuser = $getuser->getuser();
    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return response()->json([
        'error' => $validator->errors()->all()
        ]);
    }else{
        
        $lastapptid = DB::table('AllDrugPresc')->max('Presc_Num');
        $newid = $lastapptid + 1;
        foreach($presdrug->drugname as $key => $d){
            return DB::table('AllDrugPresc')
            ->insert([
                'Presc_Num'=>$newid,
                'Date'=>Carbon::now(),
                'Time'=>date('H:i:s'),
                'Drug_Id'=>$presdrug->drugid[$key],
                'Drug_Name'=>$d,
                'Prescription'=>$presdrug->drugprescription[$key],
                'Hospital_No'=>'44455eee',
                'Surname'=>'rrr',
                'Other_Name'=>'rrr',
                'Age'=>44,
                'Sex'=>'ee',
                'Account'=>'ee',
                'Account_Category'=>'ddd',
                'Clinic'=>$presdrug->consultclinic,
                'Diagnosis'=>$presdrug->drugdiagnosis,
                'Prescribed_By'=>'wwwe',
                'Qty_given'=>2,
                'Total_Cost'=>33
            ]);
        }
    }
}
```

Can someone tell me what i am doing wrong please. Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you show full form html? And you want to insert every name with the same id to every row in database??

Comment: Yes exactly you get what I meant. Yes

Comment: Those form inputs will be generated from a jQuery code. The jQuery code is not indenting on stack overflow I don't know why.

Comment: But that's how the form would be generating from the code. That's why I placed it as assuming

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because $presdrug->drugid is a string type, you can not use foreach. One more thing, you are using the undefined variable $newId. Try the code below:

```
//....
$lastapptid = DB::table('AllDrugPresc')->max('Presc_Num');

foreach($presdrug->drugname as $key => $d){
    $newid = $lastapptid + ($key + 1);
    
//...
```

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252916/discussion-on-answer-by-khang-tran-laravel-multiple-fields-upload); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 1):

First of all make a validated class that will validate the inputs by running php artisan make: request DrugValidationRequest

```
class DrugValidationRequest extends FormRequest
{
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'consultclinic' => 'required|string',
            'drugdiagnosis' => 'required|string',
            'drugpassword'  => 'required|string',
        ];
    }

    public function messages()
    {
        return [
            'consultclinic.required' => 'Give your required message',
            'drugdiagnosis.required' => 'Give your required message',
            'drugpassword.required'  => 'Give your required message',
        ];
    }
}
```

Then do the following code. Don't insert the data using a loop. in stead of making data into loop and then insert directly

```
 public function prescribedrugs(DrugValidationRequest $presdrug)
{
    $getUser         = new Getloggedinuserservice();
    $getLoggedInUser = $getuser->getuser();
    $lastapptid      = DB::table('AllDrugPresc')->max('Presc_Num');
    $newid           = $lastapptid + 1;
    $paramData       = [];

    foreach ($presdrug->drugname as $key => $d) {
        $paramData[] = [
            'Presc_Num'        => $newid,
            'Date'             => Carbon::now(),
            'Time'             => date('H:i:s'),
            'Drug_Id'          => $presdrug->drugid[$key],
            'Drug_Name'        => $d,
            'Prescription'     => $presdrug->drugprescription[$key],
            'Hospital_No'      => '44455eee',
            'Surname'          => 'rrr',
            'Other_Name'       => 'rrr',
            'Age'              => 44,
            'Sex'              => 'ee',
            'Account'          => 'ee',
            'Account_Category' => 'ddd',
            'Clinic'           => $presdrug->consultclinic,
            'Diagnosis'        => $presdrug->drugdiagnosis,
            'Prescribed_By'    => 'wwwe',
            'Qty_given'        => 2,
            'Total_Cost'       => 33
        ];
    }

    return DB::table('AllDrugPresc')->insert($paramData);

}
```

Also in the handler add the validation rule too.

```
 public function render($request, Throwable $e)
{
    if ($e instanceof ValidationException) {
        if ($request->ajax()) {
            return response()->json($e->validator->getMessageBag()->toArray());
        }a
        return redirect()->back()->withErrors($e->validator->getMessageBag()->toArray())->withInput();
    }
 
   throw new \Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException($validator);

}
```